# How to Use Dynamic Image(URL) form json in bitmap

Tags: android, json, image, pdf, printing

I followed [this](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=4747&scat=61&pcat=52) to print Sample Reciepts..

This is my Json data

```
    {
    "response": {
        "status": "http://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-print-raw-ESC-POS-commands-from-PHP-directly-to-the-client-printer/php-print-esc-pos-sample-receipt.png"
    }
}
```

Here I have parsed JOSN in some other activity..and passed that in a intent.
and I assigned that url/json response to a string **"Test22"**

now `Test22 = http://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-print-raw-ESC-POS-commands-from-PHP-directly-to-the-client-printer/php-print-esc-pos-sample-receipt.png`

So I want to add this string in the Bitmap.. so that i can print..

Over there in EPSON sample code for printing image from a Location they have used this

```
Bitmap logoData = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.store);
        StringBuilder textData = new StringBuilder();
        final int barcodeWidth = 2;
        final int barcodeHeight = 100;
```

Here sample is printing Image from R.drawable But I want to Print it from URL
if its storing after printing It should delete Image...

Can any one suggest me what I need to add at R.drawable in this case...

Actually Its a Pdf I am converting it to a image..
Can any one suggest me PDF to bitmap  or Print a Image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.drawable` is only from images packed in app.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Replace from EPSON code

```
Bitmap logoData = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.store);
```

to

```
Bitmap logoData = getBitmapFromURL("http://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-print-raw-ESC-POS-co‌​mmands-from-PHP-directly-to-the-client-printer/php-print-esc-pos-sample-receipt.p‌​ng");
```

Comment: ok @joushua sir, so here How can I use this insted of r.drawable in epson sample code which is there in my question

Comment: @Madhu `Bitmap logoData = getBitmapFromURL(url);`

Comment: Here My url is Test22(hence I have taken it from json and passing intent) where is I nee to replace it..

Comment: @Madhu I assume taht your EPSON code is working. Then, `Bitmap logoData = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.store);` is replaced by `Bitmap logoData = getBitmapFromURL("http://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-print-raw-ESC-POS-commands-from-PHP-directly-to-the-client-printer/php-print-esc-pos-sample-receipt.png");`

Comment: thanks a Lot its working fine please update your answer.. with update1.. I will accept it..